# Number of occurences in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency

I've the following data frame and I want to count the occurrences of each row by the first column and append as another column say "freq" to the data frame:

df:

```
gene    a    b    c
abc     1    NA   1
bca     NA   1    1
cba     1    2    1
```

my df is bigger, so this is only an example to scalable.

The desire dataframe is that:

```
gene    a    b    c    freq
abc     1    NA   1     2
bca     NA   1    1     2
cba     1    2    1     3
```

the codes what I have tried is that:

```
g <- df %>% mutate(numtwos = rowSums(. > 0))
```

or

```
df$freq <- apply(df , 1, function(x) length(which(x>0)))
```

But it is not working because if in a row should have (for example) 150 repetitions, I obtain only 2 for every row.

Any help or other point of view is welcome!

Thanks

Comment: @Gregor Thomas exactly, Na is NA, I just update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use first convert the `Na` to "NA"

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(a:c), ~ as.numeric(na_if(., "Na"))) %>%
   mutate(freq = rowSums(select(., a:c), na.rm = TRUE))
#  gene  a  b c freq
#1  abc  1 NA 1    2
#2  bca NA  1 1    2
#3  cba  1  1 1    3
```

Here, the values are all 1s, so it is the same as getting the sum of non-NA

```
df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(a:c), ~ as.numeric(na_if(., "Na"))) %>%
   mutate(freq = rowSums(!is.na(select(., a:c))))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(gene = c("abc", "bca", "cba"), a = c("1", "Na", 
"1"), b = c("Na", "1", "1"), c = c(1L, 1L, 1L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: oh sorry, I have NA, not Na

Comment: @WindSur then, you can remove the first `mutate_at`

Comment: I have more than 3 columns, so should I use `mutate(freq = rowSums(select(.>0), na.rm = TRUE))` ?

Comment: @WindSur, your first column is not numeric.  sso, it would be `mutate(freq = rowSums(!is.na(select_if(., is.numeric)))`

Comment: Or use `select(., -1)`

Comment: I've tried with the next code, but it doesn't work: `g <- gain %>% mutate(freq = rowSums(!is.na(select_if(. > 0, -1))))`  gain is the name of my df

Comment: @WindSur you changed my `select_if`. It should be different `select_if(., is.numeric)`

Comment: @WindSur  the `select` is for selecting the columns, let's say you want to select columns having only values greater than 0, then `select_if(data, ~ all(. > 0))`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used R for a while, so I won't paste in the code, but you can create a new df groupping the initial one by gene and merge/join it to your initial df in another line of code.